# How do I check the memory being used by my C code?

Tags: c, memory

I am a new C programmer and the pointers + arrays are messing me over a lot. I don't get any errors and the code runs fine...until somewhere in the middle the code starts acting up because some element in an array is set to something other than I wanted it to be. I wanted to know if there is a program that visualizes the memory of the code after it has finished running?

E.g after I run:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int array[2] = {0,1};
    array[1] = 4;
    printf("%d\n",array[1]);
    }
```

It will show a block of memory where array has two elements with 0 and 4 .

Right now to avoid running into a problem where the array contains elements from previous action I clear the memory of that array by doing:

```
memset(tokenized,0,MAX_CHARS);
```

It seems to work, but I don't know if its actually doing what I think it's doing at the back end.

Edit:
I am using Valgrind now and I just want to know, how do I know what line the error is referring to?
For example I got this:

```
==24394== Source and destination overlap in strncpy(0x7ff000006, 0x7ff000006, 6)
==24394==    at 0x4C2C236: strncpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24394==    by 0x400D8A: tokenize_quotes (in /home/zee/Documents/seng265/repos/assignment2/a.out)
==24394==    by 0x40184E: main (in /home/zee/Documents/seng265/repos/assignment2/a.out)
==24394== 
==24394== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24394==    at 0x4C2C007: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24394==    by 0x400E06: tokenize_quotes (in /home/zee/Documents/seng265/repos/assignment2/a.out)
==24394==    by 0x40184E: main (in /home/zee/Documents/seng265/repos/assignment2/a.out)
==24394==
```

But I don't know what line the error is on?  I know its something about strcpy 
Thanks!

Comment: You can easily verify it by using a debugger, and check some random entries in `tokenized` before and after the call to `memset`.

Comment: I always run valgrind like this: valgrind -v --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes <path_to_your_executable>. It always show line number, so it should help (I just don't remember which command switches that on so I copied it from one of my scripts).

Comment: Compile your code with `-g` to instruct the compiler to also produce debugging information. Tools like `Valgrind` and `gdb` can then use this information to map virtual addresses to lines in the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/):

> Valgrind is a GPL'd system for debugging and profiling Linux programs.
>   With Valgrind's tool suite you can automatically detect many memory
>   management and threading bugs, avoiding hours of frustrating
>   bug-hunting, making your programs more stable. You can also perform
>   detailed profiling to help speed up your programs.​

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

valgrind is nice tool try using that.

```
avinash@ubuntu:~$ valgrind ./test
==2559== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2559== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2559== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2559== Command: ./test
==2559== 
4
==2559== 
==2559== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2559==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2559==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==2559== 
==2559== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2559== 
==2559== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2559== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
avinash@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Valgrind is the tool you are looking for: Valgrind is really really *really* good for checking uninitialised memory and invalid memory accesses (etc), but in this case, I don't Valgrind is going to answer the question.

If you want to check that memory is zero (i.e. you've reset it properly), you can use

```
char test = 0;
unsigned i;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHARS; i++) {
   test |= tokenized[i];
}
printf("Memory %s zero\n", test == 0 ? "is" : "isn't");
```

(After the loop, `test` will be 0 only if every single byte in `tokenized` is zero.)

You won't want this permanently in your code though: you can trust `memset` does what you want if you pass it the right parameters.

---

The error you are getting from Valgrind is a different problem: you happen to be calling `strncpy` with two pointers that point to the same data, e.g.

```
 strncpy(ptr, ptr, 6);
```

and that data is uninitialised. As in, it is essentially random: your program hasn't written anything to that block of memory yet.

(Also, if you compile with `-g` (debugging symbols) Valgrind will give you more informative output, including line numbers.)